# Store values using cookie/session on javascript

Tags: javascript

how can I store this value from hidden field to a cookie/session using javascript

```
function SelectedRowsHidden() {
                var hiddenField = $("#<%= SelectedRowsState.ClientID %>");
                var selectedValues = "";

                for (var row in selectedRows) {
                    if (selectedRows[row])
                        selectedValues = selectedValues + row;
                }
                //hiddenField.val(selectedValues); //selectedvalues must be stored on cookie or session
                //codes for cookies / session
            }
```

after creating cookie / session how will i pass that to another session.

```
function restoreSelectedRows(){
                //var getRowState = document.getElementById('<%= SelectedRowsState.ClientID %>').innerHTML;
                var getRowState = $("#SelectedRowsState").val(); // gives me undefined value
                $("#jqGrid").jqGrid('setSelection', getRowState, true);
                //code here
            }
```

I really dont know how will I achieve this. Thanks

Comment: Have you read any documentation on javascript cookie access? E.g. http://www.quirksmode.org/js/cookies.html or https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.cookie

Comment: i dont know how will i insert that on function.

Comment: if i add this document.cookie = selectedValues; how will i call this on another function.

Comment: can you help me with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check this code.Here i try to cover the following points :

1.)Create cookies using Javascript.

2.)read Cookie value using session on another page.

**I want to clear one thing before this you cannot set session in javascript because session is server side functionality.**

**First page to write cookies using javascript :**

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<title></title>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function writeCookie() {
        var exdays = null;//Specify how much days you want cookie age
        var value = document.getElementById('HiddenField1').value;
        var exdate = new Date();
        exdate.setDate(exdate.getDate() + exdays);
        var c_value = escape(value) + ((exdays == null) ? "" : "; expires=" + exdate.toUTCString());
        document.cookie = "TestCookie=" + c_value;//Cookie name with value

    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>
    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Click" 
        OnClientClick="writeCookie();"/>
    <asp:HiddenField ID="HiddenField1" runat="server" Value="HiddenFieldValue" />
</div>
</form>
```

**Second page to read Cookies using Session :**

**ASPX file :**

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
 <head runat="server">
   <title></title>
 </head>
 <body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>
    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
</div>
</form>
</body>
 </html>
```

**CS file:**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    HttpCookie aCookie = Request.Cookies["TestCookie"];
    if (aCookie != null)
    {
        Label1.Text = aCookie.Value;
        session["hiddenvalue"] = aCookie.Value;
    }
    else
    {
        //Cookie not set.
    }
}
```

Hope this cover your doubts if still something missing please let me know.

Comment: can i use  session["hiddenvalue"] to call the variable on javascipt.

Comment: how can I remove the session from javascript?

Comment: No you can't remove session value directly but if you assign session value in hiddenfield,update this value then again assign to session will work here.